# Bootstrap NavBar Brand Text Breaking out when resized

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I recently started work on a template I downloaded and as always I like to check that the responsive side of things is working after making all of the basic changes needed.

Luckily enough I am only having one issue and that is when I resize the browser the "brand text" within the navbar breaks out rather then resizing.

I would be greatful if anyone can offer advice on how to fix this issue.

Please find the relevant code below

```
<section id="header" class="appear"></section>
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" data-0="line-height:100px; height:100px; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);" data-300="line-height:60px; height:60px; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,1);">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="fa fa-bars color-white"></span>
                </button>
                <h1><a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html" data-0="line-height:90px;" data-300="line-height:50px;">          DirectDesignKent Computer Repairs
                </a></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav" data-0="margin-top:20px;" data-300="margin-top:5px;">
                    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#section-about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#section-contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.navbar {
    line-height: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom:0;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom:0;
}

.nav li {
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom:0;
}

.nav>li>a {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 13px;
    letter-spacing: .1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav>li>a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: none;
}

.navbar-nav {
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom:0;   
}

.navbar .navbar-nav > .active > a {
    color: #fff;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav > .active > a {
    padding-bottom: 22px;
}

h1 a.navbar-brand {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-shadow: none;
}

.navbar-brand {
    padding: 0;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 90px;
}

.navbar-brand img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.navbar-toggle {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 80px;
}

.navbar-collapse.in {
    margin-top: -5px !important;
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance